# Dynamically getting info path form fields to send workflow task: SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: dynamic-data, infopath, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom workflow that uses the "Collect data from a user" action, i have it set up so as task is either approved/rejected. In the "this user" selection i want to get the email field from my sharepoint library which will be populated when the form is submitted and send
the form to corresponding email using this workflow. I have tried using "Workflow" Look up and while connected to the sharepoint site, i can access the form library however i dont know how to properly use the workflow look up wizard: does anyone know how the "Look up details" and "Find the list item" options relate? how to use them to get infopath email field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do would be to make sure you are publishing the email field to the form library. From there you should just be able to grab that field and put it right into the "This user" Section by selecting "Current item->email".

Comment: Thanks for your response, i did figure it out and essentially used a custom email utilizing the "Current item->email".